# Grab data outside a specific tag in Python BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 3.8 with BeautifulSoup4.
I am on Windows 10 and I use PyCharm.

I am kinda new with this lib but I was able to manage simple extractions. However, I have this HTML code (which I didn't make and which I cannot edit) :

```
<ul>
            <li>
               <span class="def">Achenheim</span> (Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a class="tdme" href="orgues/achenhei.htm">&gt;
                                                St-Georges : Max ROETHINGER, 1962.</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <span class="def">Adamswiller</span> (Région de Drulingen, Bas-Rhin)<ul>
                  <li>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a class="tdme" href="orgues/adamswpr.htm">&gt;
                                                Eglise protestante : George WEGMANN, 1846.</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>              
</ul>
```

So far, I was able to grab the values "Achenheim" (in the span tag), and "St-Georges : Max ROETHINGER, 1962." (in the a tag).

I would like to know if it's possible to grab the following values:

```
(Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
```

I struggle because it's not really inside any specific tag, beside a li tag. But when I try to grab the text value of the li tag, I get this :

```
<li>
<span class="def">Achenheim</span> (Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)<ul>
<li>
<ul>
<li>
<a class="tdme" href="orgues/achenhei.htm">&gt;
                                                St-Georges : Max ROETHINGER, 1962.</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

My code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as requests

r = requests.get('url_link')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

regions = soup.select('ul li')
for r in regions:
    print(str(r))
```

It's not what I was expecting :(
Anyone knows how to grab a data that it outside a specific tag please? Again, I am trying to get :

```
(Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
```

Triming and slicing cannot be a solution in my case :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your strategy selecting the elements and use the `<span>` instead:

```
for e in soup.select('ul span'):
    print(e.text)
    print(e.next_sibling.strip())
    print(' '.join(e.find_next('a').text.split()))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul>
            <li>
               <span class="def">Achenheim</span> (Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a class="tdme" href="orgues/achenhei.htm">&gt;
                                                St-Georges : Max ROETHINGER, 1962.</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <span class="def">Adamswiller</span> (Région de Drulingen, Bas-Rhin)<ul>
                  <li>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a class="tdme" href="orgues/adamswpr.htm">&gt;
                                                Eglise protestante : George WEGMANN, 1846.</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>              
</ul>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('ul span'):
    print(e.text)
    print(e.next_sibling.strip())
    print(' '.join(e.find_next('a').text.split()))
```

##### Output

```
Achenheim
(Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
> St-Georges : Max ROETHINGER, 1962.

Adamswiller
(Région de Drulingen, Bas-Rhin)
> Eglise protestante : George WEGMANN, 1846.
```

Comment: Thank you for the very completed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.find_next_sibling` with `text=True` parameter:

```py
for d in soup.select(".def"):
    print(d.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
```

Prints:

```
(Région de Mundolsheim, Bas-Rhin)
(Région de Drulingen, Bas-Rhin)
```